# How can I create or change a text file within a subdirectory in Cmd?

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd, save, subdirectory

Just need a little help with cmd if possible.
I'm trying to save a set of variables in a subdirectory.
I've managed to create a subdirectory and a file containing
the saved variables inside the parent folder, but I can't for
the life of me figure out how to move the save file into the
subdirectory.
This is an example of the code I'm using to save variables and
create the folder:

```
(
md Saves
echo %variable1%
echo %variable2%
echo %variable3%
) >variables.save
```

How can I make it so the 'variables.save' file is put into the 'Saves' folder?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create the subfolder and then echo the variables into the text file in the subfolder.

```
md Saves >nul
(
    echo %variable1%
    echo %variable2%
    echo %variable3%
) >Saves\variables.save
```